# Android theme generator for 2.3 version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

Is there any theme generator to build a custom style? If not, Is there any page to download built themes? To 2.3 version. The generator that I know is to more high versions

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for answer but I use these 2 site to generate theme:-

1. [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/)
2. [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100)

Comment: Holo Theme used in above URL requires Android 3 or above. Does not work with 2.3. If you found any site, please advise.

Comment: @CedricSimon Check this out :- Yeah you can use it:- [Is it possible to combine Holo Colors with HoloEverywhere ?](http://android-holo-colors.com/faq.html#holoeverywhere)